# SVG flickering in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, internet-explorer-11

I am experiencing heavy flickering when using SVG/Image in Internet Explorer 11 when using a filter. The image is a transparent PNG.

The HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <defs>
        <filter id="parent_t1">
          <feGaussianBlur id="parent_fe_1" stdDeviation="0" />
        </filter>
   </defs>
   <image filter="url('#parent_t1')" x="0" y="0" width="273px" height="600px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/test.png" />
</svg>
```

The filter URL part is injected to the HTML as follows:

```
filter="url(&quot;'#parent_t1&quot;)"
```

The SVG is injected into the HTML page in Javascript.  I assume that IE11 flickers as the result of consecutive calls to the same URL with the #parent_t1 hash.  In my page I have various elements, it only happens when I scroll to the area where the SVG stars to appear in the page. When I remove the url attribute of the filter property the flicker is gone. That's why I assume that behind the scene IE11 calls is calling the page repeatedly every SVG redraw.

I am using latest jQuery library. Furthermore, this weird behavior is not happening in other browsers. Didn't test it in older IE version.

**Here's a jsFiddle - run it on IE11:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DeCbx/3/

Any idea how to solve this? - thanks.

Comment: Works for me in IE11... don't see any flickering. But in Chrome, the image doesn't even show up.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Weird, tested it in three different computers and get the same results.  Let's see if other people have the same issue...

Comment: @IdanShechter do they have the same graphic drivers?

Comment: @DanielA.White they have a different card, but it might be a driver issue.. just might.

Comment: Worked fine on my machine (Win7/IE11) when I shrink the fiddle window and scroll.